# How to pause a video when browser fails jreject plugin test?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the [jReject jquery plugin](http://jreject.turnwheel.com/#documentation). It detects the users browser version and presents links to updates. I would like to pause a video using the options.onFail() event and then restart it with the options.afterClose() event. So far no luck.

here is my code:

```
<video id="intro-video" autoplay="autoplay">  --sources in here-- </video>

<script type="text/javascript">
   (function ($) {
      options.onFail( function() {
         $('#intro-video').get(0).pause();   
      });
      options.afterClose( function () {
         $('#intro-video').get(0).play();
      });
   }(jQuery));
</script>
```